# Elegant Protractor Logging on browser.wait()

Tags: xpath, protractor, e2e-testing

For some time now, our team has been using the Protractor/Jasmine combo in order to do E2E testing and it has worked out great for us.

Recently, I've been assigned the task of improving the logging and have noticed 2 areas in our code where the logging could be improved.

One of these areas is with using `browser.wait()`. We're currently using the method in the form of `browser.wait(condition, timeOut)` and excluding the third parameter which is a message to be written to the console in case of a failure.

I decided to comb the code and insert a message into each of these methods and the result has been OK. Although the code works, I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing this.

I'm currently saving the XPath of whatever element I'm waiting on and then if that fails, displaying a message in the form: `getWait() timeout due to <element_name> { XPath = <element_XPath> } being not visible or enabled such that you can click it.` The pattern changes if we're using `isPresent()`, `elementToBeClickable()`, `visibilityOf()`, etc.

Is there a way of getting the current context of the code I'm executing when `browser.wait()` is executed? Can I instead display the element or more information on what caused the timeOut?

Let me know if I can clarify further. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even I came faced the same problem when using `browser.wait` where it won't show any detailed log on time out. So what I have done is, I created a wrapper class for waitHandling and added failure messages based on the wait type. Kindly have a look at below code.

```
var browserWaitHandler = function () {
   var expectedConditions = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
   var defaultWaitTime = 5000;

    this.waitForElementPresent = function (_element,customWaitTime) {
       return browserWait(expectedConditions.presenceOf(_element),customWaitTime,"Wait timeout after waiting for element to be Present with locator "+_element.locator().toString());
    };

    this.waitForElementVisible = function (_element,customWaitTime) {
       return browserWait(expectedConditions.visibilityOf(_element),customWaitTime,"Wait timeout after waiting for element to be Visible with locator "+_element.locator().toString());
    };

    this.waitForElementClickable = function (_element,customWaitTime) {
        return browserWait(expectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(_element),customWaitTime,"Wait timeout after waiting for element to be clickable with locator "+_element.locator().toString())
    };

    this.waitForElementContainsText = function (_element,expectedText,customWaitTime) {
        return browserWait(expectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(_element,expectedText),customWaitTime,"Wait timeout after waiting for element to Contain text as "+expectedText+" with locator "+_element.locator().toString())
    };


    var browserWait = function (waitCondition,customWaitTime,timeoutMessage) {
        return browser.wait(waitCondition,customWaitTime | defaultWaitTime,timeoutMessage);
    };
};
```

And also in protractor we have a method called `locator()` which can be used with `ElementFinder` and `ElementArrayFinder` objects to get the locator that is used to find the element.Refer below example code,

```
var loginButton = element(by.buttonText("Login"));
console.log("Locator used for login button is:"+loginButton.locator().toString());

*OUTPUT:*
Locator used for login button is:by.buttonText("Login")
```

Comment: This looks nice but how would I implement it? Where would I place it in my code?

Comment: My question is, if for example, your `Login` buttons text changed to `Loginn` for whatever reason, how would you display the locator for an element that is undefined? It would be undefined because you can't find it right?